# Trying to convert users input into a word document using pandoc

Tags: python, django, pandoc

I want to take users response of a form and convert it into a templated word document that will be downloaded. I am trying to use pandoc but I am beginner at both python and django and do not know how

I am a beginner in python and do not know what to do.

This is my create_proposal.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New Financial Proposal</h2>
    <form class="form-group" action="result/" method="get"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"/>
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

And in my views.py file I have a class like this:

```
class InputPage(CreateView):
    model = CostOfGood
    template_name = 'create_proposal.html'
    fields = '__all__'
```

The class CostOfGood in models.py looks like:

```
class CostOfGood(models.Model):
    item_no = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    part_no = models.TextField()
    product_description = models.TextField()
    unitMarketPrice = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    markup = models.FloatField()
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's the exact problem? Are you using `pypandoc`, or..?

Comment: i am trying to use 'pypandoc' but do not know how. Anything else that would do the job is good too